# Format date string for Google calendar chart

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, html, google-visualization

I read a Json file using Newtonsoft.Json API with the below method. Since Google calendar chart takes date as new Date(yyyy,mm,dd) in made some formatting to the date string to get the desired format.

Json file sample

```
[
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-15",
        "Frequencies": 11
    },
    {
        "Date": "2014-January-8",
        "Frequencies": 22
    }
]
```

Method to read file

```
public string CalendarChart()
    {
        Utility utils = new Utility();
        List<Item> data = utils.ReadJsonString("CalendarChart");
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jss.Serialize(data);
        return json;
    }
```

Populate Calendar Data Table

```
function drawCalendarChart(jsonObj) {
    var months = {
        January: 0,
        February: 1,
        March: 2,
        April: 3,
        May:4,
        June: 5,
        July: 6,
        August: 7,
        September: 8,
        October: 9,
        November: 10,
        December: 11
        };
    var dataValues = eval(jsonObj)
       var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataValues);
       data.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
       data.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'Reports' });

      for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
      var splitted = dataValues[i].Date.split('-');
       data.addRow([new Date(splitted[0], months.splitted[1], splitted[2]), dataValues[i].Frequencies]);
        }

       var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('chart'));

       var options = {
         title: "Calendar Chart",
         height: 350
       };

       chart.draw(data, options);
   }
```

Basically I am splitting the Date string by '-' to get three splitted values. Then I use an array to convert from month word to month number. This should be working fine but for some reason calendar is not showing. I hard coded dates in the drawCalendarChart() function to test method and it is working fine.
I cannot determine were I'm wrong.

Comment: No body can give me an answer... or am I'm missing something in the question.